# Can't install better-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, better-sqlite3

I have tried to do node-gyp rebuild and install all the dependencies but still, nothing works here is my error

```
integer@2.1.0 install /media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/integer
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/integer/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/integer/src/integer.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/integer.node
  COPY Release/integer.node
  COPY ../build/integer.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/place_resulting_binary.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/integer/build'

> better-sqlite3@5.4.0 install /media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
  TOUCH b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_extract_sqlite3 b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
/bin/sh: 1: bot/Discord: not found
/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/deps/extract.js:8
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => { throw err; });
                                            ^

CwdError: ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/obj/gen/sqlite3'
    at fs.lstat (/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/tar/lib/mkdir.js:74:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
deps/locate_sqlite3.target.mk:16: recipe for target 'b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate' failed
make: *** [b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate] Error 1
rm b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
make: Leaving directory '/media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js-commando@0.10.0 requires a peer of sqlite@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enmap@4.7.1 requires a peer of better-sqlite-pool@github:eslachance/better-sqlite-pool but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN idostuff@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@5.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@5.4.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jeremiah/\Buildagent\npm-cache/_logs/2019-02-09T20_04_52_918Z-debug.lo
```

I have tried to do everything it says to do but nothing works I would like to use better-sqlite3 for storing my discord bots info but if we cant figure this out I will just use MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Installing of new version of nodeJs helped me to solve this issues

Comment: me too. Had a docker container building FROM node:14; changed that to node:17 and it built fine.

Comment: That is correct. needed to follow https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version lol